# Angularjs with ng-repeat and ng-show index(expandable list)

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem with ng-show index.What i want is to change ng-show index.For example:

```
 <div class="row" ng-repeat="list1 in Items track by index">
         <button ng-click="vm.showLoc($index)">

       <div class="row" ng-repeat="list2 in listGroup track by index" ng-show="..">
           <div class="row" ng-repeat="listItem in list track by index">
           </div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

When i click the button in the page,according to index value that is sent by button list that is have index value should be shown. etc.When i click the button below function runs.

```
    function showLoc(index){
    vm.show=index;
    }
```

Do you have any idea?

For example: I have 2 item in Items so i have two button.When i click the first button,i want values that belong to first listGroup[0] should be shown.When i click the second button, values that belongs to second listGroup[1] should be shown.In other words,My listGroup is also have two values but first value contains 20 item. second item contains 10 item.

Comment: What button in what page? I see neither, what is vm? Where is that function called from?

Comment: firstly, use `$index`, then try `ng-show="$index == show"` (or whatever your _ControllerAs_ name is, e.g. `$ctrl.show`)

Comment: It runs before when i click the button

Comment: I updated above code

Comment: `first list shold be shown or second list ` you mean first & second list item in listGroup should be show ? @Belhanda

Comment: No. If index value is 0, first list should be shown.

Comment: @Belhanda hope this helps http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/U3pVM/42063/ , update back if it helps i can add it as answer

Comment: @supercool when i click the first button,its value are loading properly but second button is opened automatically and it loads same values

Comment: `automatically` it doen't happen over fiddle right ? & load same values thats because of the data i used you can always use accord'ly

Comment: I think problem is '<div class="row" ng-repeat="listItem in list track by index">' I also have this line

Comment: @Belhanda add sample json you get as a response to your question.

Comment: When i click the first button it loads all data items.Second button is not open automatically right now.I am triying to fix it.

Comment: It is working now.Thank you very much @supercool.

Comment: I changed list2 in listGroup with list2 in  listGroup[index]

Comment: glad you got it working @Belhanda cheers . good day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
(function() {
    'use strict';
angular
  .module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', myCtrl);

   function myCtrl(){
       /* jshint validthis: true */
       var vm=this;
       vm.activeIndex = null;
       vm.items = [0, 1];
       vm.listGroup = [
          ['lg1a', 'lg1b', 'lg1c'],
          ['lg2a','lg2b','lg2c']
         ];
       vm.showLoc = showLoc;
       
       
       
      function showLoc(i){
        vm.activeIndex = i;
      }
      
   } 

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl as vm">

    <div class="row" ng-repeat="list1 in vm.items track by $index">
      <button ng-click="vm.showLoc($index)">
          show loc
        </button>

      <div class="row" ng-repeat="list2 in vm.listGroup[$index]" ng-show="$parent.$index == vm.activeIndex" track by $index>
        <span>{{list2}}</span>
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have ng-repeat in ng-repeat .ListGroup[0] contains some item.ListGroup[1] contains some values.

Comment: I think people are having alot of difficulty understanding your requirements could you either update my snippet above, or super cool's fiddle to illustrate your exact problem / requirement